# error in displaying google ads

Tags: android

I had declared google ads in xml as

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >


        <com.google.ads.AdView
             xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.admobdemo"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="a150cb2e31846cf" 
        ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
        ads:testDevices="AVD_for_4in_WVGA_Nexus_S,5554" />


    </RelativeLayout>
```

I have declared the namespace in XML and in manifest file also.

And i am declaring in my activity as

```
AdView adView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();
        adRequest.setTesting(true);

        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

But when i run my app i am getting the RESPONSE as

```
adRequestUrlHtml: <html><head><script src="http://www.gstatic.com/afma/sdk-core-v40.js"></script><script>AFMA_buildAdURL({"preqs":0,"u_sd":1.5,"u_w":480,"simulator":1,"msid":"com.netserv.Pungry","cap":"m,a","js":"afma-sdk-a-v4.0.2","isu":"B3EEABB8EE11C2BE770B684D95219ECB","format":"320x50_mb","net":"ed","app_name":"4.0.2.android.com.netserv.Pungry","hl":"en","u_h":800,"testing":1,"u_so":"p","u_audio":4});</script></head><body></body></html>
```

But it's not displaying in the output and i am getting error as

```
03-19 13:43:46.190: E/Ads(4983): AdView missing required XML attribute adUnitId.
```

Can i know what is the error in my code.

Thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

Take one layout in main layout when you want to show ad

```
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/addlay"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >
        </LinearLayout>
```

and in java file

```
        AdView adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
        LinearLayout addLay = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.addlay);

        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();
        // adRequest.addTestDevice(AdRequest.TEST_EMULATOR);
        addLay.addView(adView);
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Did you check this 
[image]

Also some times project clean also works ..

Are you able to see this

[image]

Comment: i tried what ever you have said. but still i am getting same error.. i am using GoogleAdMobAdsSDK-4.0.2.jar..

Comment: I add admob ad yesterday in my application and its working fine

Comment: try this one `xmlns:ads="schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.admobdemo"`

Comment: it is throwing same error. before running each time i clean will clean the project.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26469/discussion-between-chirag-saga-and-user2143817)